# How do I prevent Bitcoin-qt from having to keep reindexing the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

Is it likely that anti-malware or anti-virus software is causing this issue? (I have told such programs to exclude the Bitcoin folders from scans)

Comment: when does it reindexing? it has to finish it onces and wont do it again after.

Comment: Like the previous comment: has it finished once? If it has been up-to-date once, the re-indexing shouldn't occur anymore. When you quit Bitcoin-Qt before that point, it has to re-index again